# Passing data to nested master pages in MVC2 through ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I've been trying to figure out a way to pass data to a nested master page. I'm using a nested master page because it allows me a secondary layer of navigation on my website, which can then be extended by other views which need that secondary layer of navigation.

For some reason I'm unable to access ViewData["field"]. Compiler throws the error that ViewData is not in the context of the nested master page. And I also can't use child actions, they too do not exist in the context of the nested master page.

This is how the nested master page has been declared:
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Curator.master.cs" Inherits="Atlasweb.Views.Shared.Curator" %>

I've tried changing the "Inherits" attribute to System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage to see if it would allow me to access ViewData or child actions, but no luck.

Comment: So this is what I figured out:

When I added a new item, I selected "Nested Master Page". This construct might be older than MVC2 because MVC2 allows me to create a MasterPage and then add the attribute MasterPageFile which I can point to a [parent] master page to create nesting. Seems to work for me.  

<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official way has been outlined by MSDN [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/passing-data-to-view-master-pages-cs).

Below is how I addressed my own error if it relates to you as well.

So this is what I figured out: *Originally*, when I added a new item, I selected "Nested Master Page". This construct might be older than MVC2, because MVC2 allows me to **create a "MasterPage" and then add the attribute MasterPageFile** which I can point to a [parent] master page to create nesting. Seems to work for me.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
```